# Logstash, multiple http input with different path?

Tags: http, logstash

It is natural to have different api end point such as `/questions` `/users` in http.

Can I define http input with different path ? (I can only find examples using `http://ip:port` as an input)

I wonder if it's possible to define `http://ip:port/foo` as an input of logstash?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking at the wrong thing in Logstash. HTTP Input plugin is for some application to send data to Logstash over HTTP.

If you have an application and want to send to Logstash over HTTP and want to change how Logstash processes it based on the api endpoint from the original application then I would suggest putting a new field called `endpoint` into your message data. You application would populate that based on the endpoint which was used. Then you can use conditionals within Logstash to change the logic Logstash applies.